# Connect remote ssh to pc... pc connect vpn

Tags: ssh, remote-access, vpn, openvpn

I have:
-PC with ubuntu 18
-Install and configure ssh for remote access
-Open ssh port in my router
-My IP is dinamic, so I configure Dynamic DNS (www.noip.com).

I have remote access to my PC from another external computer, with domain no-ip and ssh port. No problem.

Now:
-I connect my PC for Tunnel VPN (openvpn) to a VPN server (VPNbook)
-Refresh my no-ip domain with the new public VPN IP.
-But I can't connect for ssh (domain no-ip and ssh port) to my PC...

Why? What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237460/ssh-into-a-server-which-is-connected-to-a-vpn-service
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/893775/cant-ssh-to-server-with-vpn-connection
- https://www.linode.com/community/questions/7381/openvpn-client-connected-to-a-server-while-listening-to-ssh

In my PC:

1. Connect VPN
2. List item

Execute:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.0.101 table 128
ip route add table 128 to 192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0f0
ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.0.1
```

Where:

- 192.168.0.101 -> Internal IP to my PC
- 192.168.0.0/24 -> subnet, calculate with "subnetcalc"
- enp2s0f0 -> it is the name of my net interface
- 192.168.0.1 -> My default-gateway

Now, i have remote access for ssh.